# How to override Site.get_current()/request.get_host() in tests

Tags: django, django-unittest

In my app I have line `if request.get_host() == Site.objects.get_current().domain`. The problem is in my tests this condition is never `True`. `request.get_host()` returns `testserver` and `Site.objects.get_current` returns `example.com`. I know that I can add `SERVER_NAME` to `request` but I want change globally not in every single request.

Answer (score 1):

You can control `request.get_host()` behaviour by passing **HTTP_HOST** to `client.get()` method. You can use SERVER_NAME, as you mentioned, but HTTP_HOST is preferred, because it is used by get_host() as is, and SERVER_NAME is used with respect to SERVER_PORT variable, so you can get "SERVER_NAME:SERVER_PORT" in some non-default port cases.

So your test could look like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class FooTests(TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        self.client.get('/', HTTP_HOST='example.com')
```

If you want to do it in whole test case class, you can override `client_class` like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client


class MyClient(Client):
    HTTP_HOST = 'example.com'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('HTTP_HOST', self.HTTP_HOST)
        return super(MyClient, self).get(*args, **kwargs)


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    client_class = MyClient


class FooTests(MyTestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.client.get('/')
```

Or you can write a Mixin for `TestCase`, which will look similar to my previous example.

Finally, you can override `django.test.TestCase.client_class`. This will work globally, but it looks a bit hacky, so I would not recommend you to do that.